# Removing redundant regex?

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have a list of very simple regex represented as strings (by "very simple", I mean only containing `.*`).  Every string in the list starts and ends with `.*`.  For example, I could have

```
rs = [.*a.*, .*ab.*, .*ba.*cd.*, ...]
```

What I would like to do is keep track of those patterns that are a subset of another.  In this example, `.*a.*` matches everything `.*ab.*` does, and more.  Hence, I consider the latter pattern to be redundant.

What I thought to do was to split the strings on `.*`, match up corresponding elements, and test if one `startswith` the other.  More specifically, consider `.*a.*` and `.*ab.*`.  Splitting these on `.*`

```
a = ['', 'a', '']
b = ['', 'ab', '']
```

and `zip`ping them together gives

```
c = [('', ''), ('a', 'ab'), ('', '')]
```

And then,

```
all(elt[1].startswith(elt[0]) for elt in c)
```

returns `True` and so I conclude that `.*ab.*` is indeed redundant if `.*a.*` is included in the list.

Does this make sense and does it do what I am trying to do?  Of course, this approach gets complicated for a number of reasons, and so my next question is, is there a better way to do this that anyone has encountered previously?

Comment: Look into this.  It requires an understanding of the state machines and formal grammars that regular expressions rely upon http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/283838/is-one-regular-language-subset-of-another

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Thanks for your reply.  I've seen this post, and a related post on SO that references [this](https://github.com/ferno/greenery) package, but it is computationally prohibitive to use.  I was hoping there was a naive approach that was simple-ish and would work for at least some cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this problem you need to find the minimal DFAs for both the regex and compare them.
Here is the link of a discussion of same problem- 
[How to tell if one regular expression matches a subset of another regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363397/how-to-tell-if-one-regular-expression-matches-a-subset-of-another-regular-expres)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming every letter combination is surrounded by `.*` and does not have it in the middle, the approach would almost work. Instead of startswith you need to check for contains, though.

```
reglist = ['.*a.*', '.*ab.*', '.*ba.*', '.*cd.*']
patterns = set(x.split('.*')[1] for x in reglist)
remove = []
for x in patterns:
    for y in patterns:
        if x in y and x != y:
            remove.append(y)

print (['.*{}.*'.format(x) for x in sorted(patterns - set(remove))])
```

gives you

```
['.*a.*', '.*cd.*']
```