# Detect if regex accepts a subset of another regex or not?

Tags: regex

Is it feasible to detect, in regex, if one expression matches a subset of another? Obviously generating all possible inputs and measuring is one way to do it, but it's way too slow.

Comment: please provide more details with examples

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6363397/how-to-tell-if-one-regular-expression-matches-a-subset-of-another-regular-expres

Comment: Thanks, @WiktorStribiżew, this is a dupe of that question :)

Comment: Glad I could help finding it :)