# Checking if two Python regex patterns are equivalent

Tags: python, regex

I want to write a regex in [`re.VERBOSE`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.VERBOSE) mode, but I'm not confident that I'll add the verbose part without error.

I remember that, theoretically, the equivalence of two regexes (without backreferences, at least) can be found by generating their automata and trying to find a graph bijection. But there's no instance method I can see for comparing regexes.

Is there a way to either generate the automaton of a regex or directly compare them, preferably with the standard library?

(I've already decided on a different solution to my problem, but this is still of interest to me.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the undocumented `re.DEBUG` feature:

```
>>> r1 = re.compile("foo[bar]baz", re.DEBUG)
literal 102
literal 111
literal 111
in
  literal 98
  literal 97
  literal 114
literal 98
literal 97
literal 122
>>> r2 = re.compile("""foo   # foo!
...                    [bar] # b or a or r!
...                    baz   # baz!""", re.VERBOSE|re.DEBUG)
literal 102
literal 111
literal 111
in
  literal 98
  literal 97
  literal 114
literal 98
literal 97
literal 122
```

If the output is identical, `r1` and `r2` are identical as well.

Comment: More underdocumented than documented. Also, while trying to write a function to check equality of regexes, I found that, due to `re.compile` caching its results, `re.DEBUG` might not give output. And that it's not theoretical equivalence of regex, so this only works for `re.VERBOSE` changes. Here is my implementation, with examples: http://pastebin.com/DeCWLmF8 (Feel free to add from this comment to your answer.)

Comment: I'm disappointed that `re` doesn't save the debug output, and that I can't force a recompile with `re.DEBUG`.

Comment: Raised an issue about `re.DEBUG` not forcing a recompile: http://bugs.python.org/issue20426

Comment: @leewangzhong: consider raising a bug for adding a method for this like `re.compile(ur'yada').equivalent(re.compile(ur'yada'))` :)

Comment: You mean a feature request?